# override alt-f4 closing tkinter window in python 3.6 and replace it with something else

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I spent a long time reading through past posts and didn't find quite what I need.

I'm making a kiosk-type window using tkinter. I set it to open fullscreen. I want to override the standard alt-f4 command to close it. I don't want it completely uncloseable though. I'd like to instead make up my own keyboard shortcut (alt-ctrl-g-3 or something like that).

I tried some of the suggestions for overriding alt-f4 and couldn't get them to work. In my **init** function I included:

```
self.bind('<Alt-Key-F4>', self.ignorekey())
.
.
.
def self.ignorekey(self)
    pass
```

Comment: Can you post what methods you've tried? It could also be that your OS is still capturing the keystroke and sending the signal.

Comment: as far as capturing the alt-f4 that's the only method I tried since as far as I know that's the proper way to do it. I tried different identifiers for alt-f4 that I saw come up in various posts. I should mention that I'm using Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to hook the <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> or pressing the X or any other way as far as I know:

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", do_exit)
```

where `do_exit()` is the callback function and `root` is your main window.

This binding does not pass an event object. As far as I can see this should work for any platform.

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

pressed_f4 = False  # Is Alt-F4 pressed?

def do_exit():
    global pressed_f4
    print('Trying to close application')
    if pressed_f4:  # Deny if Alt-F4 is pressed
        print('Denied!')
        pressed_f4 = False  # Reset variable
    else:
        close()     # Exit application

def alt_f4(event):  # Alt-F4 is pressed
    global pressed_f4
    print('Alt-F4 pressed')
    pressed_f4 = True

def close(*event):  # Exit application
    root.destroy()

root.bind('<Alt-F4>', alt_f4)
root.bind('<Escape>', close)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",do_exit)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure that the callback from `root.bind('<Alt-F4>', alt_f4)` always will run before the callback from `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",do_exit)`. You may have to do more research to establish that.

Comment: hm, but wouldn't that stop the window from closing in every situation? I was hoping to be able to create a special shortcut key combo that would be the only thing that closes the window. Basically I'm making this for a public kiosk and I don't want people to be able to use any standard keyboard shortcut or mouse click to be able to get out of the program.

Comment: You can bind any key to a function that will close the window. So make another function which closes the window and bind something to it. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Ah OK, maybe I misunderstood what this does. I thought it was setting a property of the window saying anytime it closed. My main problem at the moment is actually binding the alt-f4 keypress. When I run this code it instantly shows the messagebox saying alt-f4 was pressed even though it wasn't and when I do hit alt-f4 it closes the window rather than executing the function:

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
       
        self.bind('<Alt-Key-F4>', self.ignorekey())

    def ignorekey(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("Invalid Email Address", "You hit alt-f4")

Comment: Didn't quite understand that...  I'm including an example of usage in my answer.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, was looking at it on mobile and didn't see it. Ill give that a try.

Comment: OK, thanks, yeah I tried that code you added and alt-f4 still closed the window.