# Prevent a Python Tkinter window from being closed (including Alt+F4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, window, python-3.7

I'm building a Tkinter app that will ask users to set a password before using the computer. Therefore, it needs to be unclosable, which includes disabling <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

I have tried using `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", preventClose)` where `preventClose` is a function (shown below). **Note:** This is not a duplicate of [override alt-f4 closing tkinter window in python 3.6 and replace it with something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358014/override-alt-f4-closing-tkinter-window-in-python-3-6-and-replace-it-with-somethi). I want a completely unclosable window, not just to remap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

This is the method I've tried using the `preventClose` function:

```py
def preventClose():
    pass
```

and this Tkinter protocol:

```py
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", preventClose)
```

This has not been able to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> like described in [Unclosable window using tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157521/unclosable-window-using-tkinter).

I do not see any error messages, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is not disabled like I want it to be.

Some basic information:

- Windows 10 Home 64-bit
- Python 3.7

Comment: it seems problem on Windows becuase it works correctly on Linux Mint.

Comment: `WM_DLELTE_WINDOW` - you spelt delete wrong.

Comment: @HenryYik, Thanks so much! I can't believe I overlooked that!

Answer (score 1):

woop okay found something on a diff question here

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

pressed_f4 = False  # Is Alt-F4 pressed?

def do_exit():
    global pressed_f4
    print('Trying to close application')
    if pressed_f4:  # Deny if Alt-F4 is pressed
        print('Denied!')
        pressed_f4 = False  # Reset variable
    else:
        close()     # Exit application

def alt_f4(event):  # Alt-F4 is pressed
    global pressed_f4
    print('Alt-F4 pressed')
    pressed_f4 = True

def close(*event):  # Exit application
    root.destroy()

root.bind('<Alt-F4>', alt_f4)
root.bind('<Escape>', close)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",do_exit)

root.mainloop()
```